# How to get min/max price statisitics per article with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get statistic data for a available articles stored in a MySQL 5.x database.

The information I am looking for is:

- How many items available of each article_id
- What is the min, max price (`cl.price`) for each article_id

The first one is easy:

```
SELECT 
 cw.article_id, -- unique identifier
 cl.title,
 count(cw.article_id) AS c -- how many items per article id availble?
FROM 
 `articles` a 
INNER JOIN classifieds_watches cw ON a.article_id = cw.article_id
INNER JOIN classifieds cl ON cw.cl_id = cl.ID
WHERE 1
GROUP BY 
 cw.article_id
ORDER BY 
 c DESC
```

But how to get the pricing info? Can this be done in one MySQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use min & max:

```
SELECT 
   cw.article_id, -- unique identifier
   cl.title,
   count(cw.article_id) AS c -- how many items per article id availble?
   min(cl.price) as minimum,
   max(cl.price) as maximum
FROM `articles` a 
   INNER JOIN classifieds_watches cw ON a.article_id = cw.article_id
   INNER JOIN classifieds cl ON cw.cl_id = cl.ID
GROUP BY cw.article_id,cl.title
ORDER BY  c DESC
```

The `WHERE 1` it is not needed because it is allways `TRUE`. In the `GROUP BY`, you need to include all columns that don´t use aggregate functions

Comment: Excellent!! Thank you nacho.

Comment: One question: Would it be possible to update another table "statisitcs" with the output of this select directly with just one statement? Otherwise I would pull into an php array and do a foreach loop in order to insert the gained knowledge into stats table.

Comment: sure you can create a view `statistics` based on this query

Comment: query would be `CREATE VIEW statistics AS SELECT...`

Comment: Yes, you could do it with **INSERT INTO ... SELECT**, you can read about it here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html